# Verifying that the equation of a line is a tangent

Tags: geometry, circles

Consider the circle: $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ The question says to verify if the equation $y = 2x + 1$ is a tangent of the circle or not.
I was told to solve the equation but I still don't understand how that'll help in the verification.

Comment: The idea is to solve the *system* of equations $x^2+y^2=2$ and $y=2x+1$.  This is something you should do, and adding your findings on that to the Question will improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We need to check that the system

- $x^2+y^2=2$
- $y=2x+1$

has exactly one solution.

Then plug in $y$ from the second in the first equation to obtain a quadratic equation in $x$.

Comment: It has two solutions $(0.2, 1.4)$ and $(-1, -1)$ does this mean that it isn't a tangent as we we're also told to find the equation of the tangent

Comment: @FuadGbadamosi Yes indeed it seems a secant line [Plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/deuvaanutm)

Comment: @FuadGbadamosi You need to find the tangen under which conditions? Parallel to $y=2x+1$?

Comment: To find the equation of the tangent at the point(s) where the line cuts the circle is the second question

Comment: Simply evaluate the derivative at those points $m=f'(x_0)$ then the tangent is $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$. Pay attention in the evaluation of $f'(x)$ we need to divide the function in two parts $y=\pm \sqrt{2-x^2}$ and take the good one accordingly.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean are you saying I should find the gradient of the two points and general the equation according to them?

Comment: @FuadGbadamosi That's nice you can use any method to find $m=f'(x_0)$.

Comment: Good to know cause I really wanted to avoid differentiation, so does that mean I'll only get one equation that is the equation between the two points.

Comment: @FuadGbadamosi No of course! You need to find m at each point, what method are you using?

Comment: Can I just use the general equation for the tangent $yy_1 + xx_1 + g(x + x_1) + f(y + y_1) + c = 0$ to find the equation.

Comment: @FuadGbadamosi Why do not use derivative? $$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\pm \sqrt{2-x^2} \implies y'=\pm \frac{-x}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}$$ or as an alternative $$\frac{dy}{dx}=- \frac x y$$

Comment: Ohhh!!! I differentiate the equation of the circle to get my gradient for each point and form the equation of a line based on each points. <bold>Thank you sir</bold> it is now very clear to me... I'll do it now

Comment: @FuadGbadamosi You can construct those tangent lines without resorting to calculus by using the fact that the tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius at that point, or (if you know about pole-polar relationships) by computing the pole of the given line. Note also that if the tangent at the point happens to be vertical, trying to use a derivative will fail.

Comment: @amd You are right, I should have mentioned that simple geometrical interpretation! Thanks

Comment: @FuadGbadamosi As noticed by amd, we can avoid derivatives, especially if you are not confortable with that, considering for each point P the line OP and then finding the line perpendicular to that line. Recall indeed that the relation $m_1\cdot m_2=-1$ holds in that case between the angular coefficients of the two lines. That approach leads to the general formula $m=dy/dx=-x/y$ for the tangent line to a circle centered at the origin, excludind the points on the $x$ axis for which the tangent is a vertical line.

Answer (score 1):

A line may pass through a circle, touch it, or miss it altogether. In each case, how many points are there that are on both the circle and the line? Which case is the tangent? Any such point satisfies both of the equations. How many solutions do you need? How many solutions are there? Solve the eqations simultaneously and find out.

Comment: 2 solutions means it isn't a tangent line right? but I'm confused as a question under it says to find the equation(s) of the tangent(s) to the circle at the point(s) where the line cuts the circle

Comment: Correct. If it is a tangent there is only one solution. If a line cuts the circle there are 2 solutions (of the simultaneous equations). If you have found a solution (say at P) you need to find the gradient of the line from P to the centre of the circle (ie the radius), then the gradient at 90 degrees to that (use m1 * m2 = -1) which will be the gradient of the tangent at P, then the equation of the line through P which has that gradient and is therefore the tangent.

Answer (score 1):

Distance of line $Ax+By +C=0$ to the origin is given by:

$d:= |\dfrac{A0+B0+C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}|$.

With $2x-y+1=0$ we get:

$d=\dfrac{1}{√5}$.

Radius of the circle is $√2$.

Is the line a tangent to the circle ?

Comment: That's what the question asks, to verify if the line is a tangent to the circle

Comment: Fuad.If the line were a tangent to the circle we would have d=radius.

Comment: Yes it is and that's how I'm also confused, the two points I got, when I find the distance between them and the center of the circle it gives me the radius of the circle

Comment: Yes I have, even used a calculator I keep getting two points

Comment: Fuad.OK, the points are at distance r from (0,0), but the line joining the 2 points is not!!! at a distance r from the origin.1 circle and 1 line are given. This given line cannot be tangent to the circle at 2 different points. Draw it, maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on Peter's.

On the line y=2x+1, how far is the point of closest approach to the center of the circle, i.e. the origin?

The slope of a line from the center to point of closest approach is -1/m where m is the slope of the given line. Here m=2, so -1/m= -1/2.

Find where (-1/2)*x =y intersects y=2x+1. Given that x and y, find the distance to the origin. If the point of closest approach is within the circle or outside the circle, it's not a tangent. It's only a tangent if the distance of the points of closest approach is equal to the radius.